# props is not initialized in react component

Tags: reactjs, flux

I have developed a Component.   In it, I am loading the data based on an Id which is passed to it like;

my Item Component code looks like

```
 ItemStore.CallItem("TenantId",this.props.MetaItemId);
```

and my calling page code looks like

```
<div className="box-body table-responsive no-padding list-relations" id="configureMM">
        <Item  MetaItemId={11} />
    </div>
    <div className="box-body table-responsive no-padding list-relations" id="configureMM">
        <Item  MetaItemId={12} />
    </div>
```

but both the times it will take the first id because this.props contains first MetaItemId but ideally it should be reinitialized when I called  `<Item  MetaItemId={12} />` but it's not, can any one please let me know what I am missing here?

Comment: Can you post the full code for `<Item >`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `ItemStore.CallItem("TenantId",this.props.MetaItemId);` in `componentWillReceiveProps` if `nextProps.MetaItemId !== this.props.MetaItemId` so it should look like this

```
this.componentWillReceiveProps = function(nextProps) { 
  if (nextProps.MetaItemId !== this.props.MetaItemId){
    ItemStore.CallItem("TenantId", nextProps.MetaItemId);
  }
}
```

This will do the call, but your component will not update unless you set state somewhere and that depends on what ItemStore.CallItem does.

Comment: I noticed if I iterate through a property that is an array in my `render()` method to filter it, the items come up as `undefined` if I'm using lodash's _.filter, but if I use `this.props.someArray.map`, they are defined. Should I be using `componentWillReceiveProps` to wait until the props are populated from a network request?

Comment: Got it working, looks like `componentWillUpdate` is the ticket.